# What is a correct way to say that you took the metro and drove for three stations?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, american-english

I took the metro/underground/subway (train?)
I drove for/past three stations

My station - 1st station - 2nd station - Destination (3rd station)

Comment: You drove the metro or were you a passenger?

Answer (score 2):

I took the metro/underground/subway and rode three stops.

Answer (score 1):

> I took the metro for 3 stops (or stations).

You don't say that you drove the transport if you're a passenger.

Another option is to use *ride*, as in:

> I rode the metro for 3 stations.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that your destination was the third stop after you boarded, or that you rode for three stops. You could also say that you rode for three segments, but I don't know if non-transit people say that.

After you board, you don't get off the train the first and second times it stops.

But the third time the train stops, you do get off since that is your destination.

Hence you could say that your destination was the third stop after you got on the train.